# how to use all ordinal values into web_submit_data, where the ordinal values are entityID's which are dynamic

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I got the ordinal all values for entity ID's that are dynamic for each transaction type, I have to use all those values into web_submit_data, where I have to replace the entityID values with ordinal values and number of entities to be submitted, depends on the count that I get from ordinal all.

```
web_submit_data("save details",
"Action=htps://abcefg",
"Method=POST".
Referer=https://..`your text`..",
snapshot=xyz.inf"
Mode=HTML",
ITEMDATA,
"Name=xyz", Value = ABC",ENDITEM,
"Name=efg", Value = hij",ENDITEM,
Name=entityID, Value={`ordinal all_values`}",ENDITEM,
Name=asd",Value=",ENDITEM,
LAST);
```

`Name=entityID,Value={ordinal_all_values}",ENDITEM` this item data is dynamic and it depends on the number of values we get in the ordinal all.

can someone help in how I need to pass all of the ordinal values to web_submit_data

Comment: See web_custom_request() for a dynamic number of name value pairs